# Azure Web App Default Domain link fails to launch App - too many HTTP redirects

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, http-error

I have just tested & deployed an App that launches to a login page using localhost. From previous experience I would expect to check my deployment by launching the app from the WebApp page inside my Resource Group on Azure. There are two links there. Both described as Default Domain. Attempting this generates the "Too many HTTP redirects" error.

[image: Page not working]

Then a page that says:

"**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**"

Where the URL space has filled up like so:
`https://rollbasewebapp.azurewebsites.net/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FError%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FHome%252FError%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FHome%25252FError%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FHome%2525252FError%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%25252` ... etc

Of course I follow the advice and clear cookies/browsing data etc. I relaunch the browser, try another browser etc

I have checked the Web App's configuration (Configuration>General) The obvious one `HTTPS Only` (off)

Okay. So the server is rejecting the browser, opening the link, on the basis that the URL resource is not available.

My thinking is that it still must have an IP address I can query. I login to Azure Portal.

```
PS > az login
```

I ping the Default Domain

```
PS > ping rollbasewebapp.azurewebsites.net

Pinging waws-prod-bay-207-9bb4.westus.cloudapp.azure.com [40.112.243.98] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 40.112.243.98:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 0, Lost = 3 (100% loss),
Control-C
```

I check the IP Address `40.112.243.98` and confirm that it is the IP Address on the Networking page of the Web Apps Resource Group. That the location of the Resource Group is `westus` etc.

This seems basic to me. If I can't `ping` a domain name that's providing me with:

- server name eg `waws-prod-bay-207-9bb4.westus.cloudapp.azure.com`
- my resouce group IP Address `40.112.243.98`
- the location of my resources `westus`

then the address is not available and hence the server won't provide the service.

So I'm asking:

- Why is this happening?
- Why does the server keep redirecting? Surely once is enough.

Any suggestions for how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: I have just tried this on another app I have in another resource group. The app eventually loaded (took around a full minute) using the Default Domain link.

Comment: Are you accessing your app using `http` or `https` ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you refer to 'accessing your app'. There is no SSL binding yet. But this should not matter. After all, in local development, `https` is used eg: `https://localhost:44302/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F`